# ECMAScript 2015, iterable destructuring expression

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am right now experimenting with the iterable destructuring expression, and i am wondering why a specific way does not work. Maybe you can help me on that.

For example that works:

```js
var x, y, myIterable = [];
myIterable[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  var count = 0;
  while(count < 2){
    yield count++;
  }
};
var myArray = Array.from(myIterable);
console.log(([x,y] = myArray) === myArray);
//OUTPUT: true
```

But if i try it this way it returns `false`, can you explain why?

```js
var x, y, myIterable = [];
myIterable[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  var count = 0;
  while(count < 2){
    yield count++;
  }
};
var myArray = Array.from(myIterable);
[x, y] = myArray;
console.log([x,y] === myArray);
//OUTPUT: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`===` compares objects by references, since `myArray` and `[x, y]` evaluate to a different array.

```
[] === []; // false
{} === {}; // false
```

Comment: odd question - knows how to play with `Symbol.iterator` and `yield`, but not that `===` compares for reference quality.

Answer (score 4):

Notwithstanding the `===` performs a *reference equality* check, per Benjamin's answer, the reason your first test returns `true` is because the result of the assignment:

```
[x, y] = myArray
```

is *not* `[x, y]`, but is instead `myArray` - the assignment operator evaluates to the RHS, not the newly assigned LHS.

So given:

```
([x,y] = myArray) === myArray
```

the LHS of the `===` evaluates to `myArray` which is exactly the same object as you have on the RHS, so the result is `true`.