# ES6 destructuring assignment - strange expression evaluation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Pointing to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250302/ecmascript-2015-iterable-destructuring-expression) I found strange behaviour in es6 destructuring assignment.

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
console.log([] = a); // Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
console.log([x] = a); // Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
console.log([x, y] = a); // Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
console.log(x, y); // 1, 2
```

I would expect to see ouptut like:

```
Array [ ]
Array [ 1 ]
Array [ 1, 2 ]
```

Can you explain this?

Comment: Result of assignment operator is it's right operand.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Could you give me any un/official reference where it is explained?

Comment: Why can't you explain it? What do you think is strange about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a bit difficult to digest, but [this is the official documentation of assignment operators](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators) (The first part of 12.14.4 being specifically the `=` operator).

Notice step 8 that reads "return `rval`". It essentially means that `a = b` will returns `b`.

So the results are correct:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
console.log([] = a); // [] = a gives a, so print Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
console.log([x] = a); // [x] = a gives a, so print Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
console.log([x, y] = a); // [x, y] = a gives a, so print Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
console.log(x, y); // x and y were destructed correctly, so print 1, 2
```

Comment: May someone explain the downvote so I can improve the answer?